# How can I use variables to slice my data, now .lookup has been deprecated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have some code I wrote using .lookup, which extracts timestamps from a datasheet, then uses those timestamps to slice some ECG data.

Previously I simply wrote

```
Timestamps = pd.DataFrame(dict(pos=m, val=df.lookup(m, m.index)))
BaselineStart = Timestamps.loc['Baseline_Start_Time']["DateTime"]
BaselineEnd = Timestamps.loc['Baseline_End_Time']['DateTime']
```

and I got my timestamps and I simply read in the ECG data, then extract the correct parts using simple slicing.

```
AstroCol_list =['Timestamp',  'ECG_Value']
Astro_ECG = pd.read_csv('A5_AstroECG.csv', usecols = AstroCol_list)
#changing the timestamp into a useable form for operations ECG Lead 2

#accessing relevant timestamp 
Astro_ECGStart = pd.to_datetime(Astro_ECG.iloc[1]['Timestamp'])

#Changing index of ECGmV so it can be sliced by timestamp, timestamp is 3.90625 ms (changed to match the Astroskin, previous value is EQ)

Astro_ECG.index = pd.date_range(start = Astro_ECGStart, periods=len(Astro_ECG), freq='3.99995ms')
Astro_ECG.index.name = 'Timestamp_ECG
```

I then would simply write to extract my data.

```
AstroBaseline = Astro_ECG[BaselineStart:BaselineEnd]
```

However, now I have to read in the data using

```
df = pd.read_csv('AstroskinA20_Edit.csv', usecols = AstroCol_list).fillna(0)
m = df.ne(0).idxmax()

# Reset the index of the DataFrame to ensure that it is sequential
df = df.reset_index()

# Create a new DataFrame with positions and values
melted_df = df.melt(id_vars='index', var_name='pos', value_name='val')

# Filter the rows with the specified positions
Timestamps= melted_df[melted_df['index'].isin(m)]
```

This works fine in importing the data, however now will no longer let me use slicing to select the relevant parts of my ECG dataset. I have tried setting both the timestamps in the ECG dataset, and those I read from my datasheet to be `DateTime` class, however I am still getting an error.

```
raise InvalidIndexError(key)
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: 0   2023-01-19 13:35:59
Name: DateTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I know the times exist, because it previously worked, however now it no longer will, and I am unsure how to fix this error.